# Angular 4 iframe Unable to hide element inside the iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I want to hide the specific element which is inside the iframe. I tried with ElementRef. But It is return empty when I use getElementsByClassName('example-class'). Here is My code

```
this.iframe.nativeElement.onload = function() {
const els = self.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('hidden-xs');
if (els.length > 0) {
    els[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

};

I also tried with iframe onload, ngoninit and ngafterviewinit.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I couldn't fix it